# An issue with the user's logging in authentication to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android Application where the user Logs in, then I send the access token to the server in order to get additional information concerning the user, but the thing is that Facebook always returns `null` to any info for the user so apparently it wasn't convinced by the access token or maybe something is missing.

Here is how the code looks like

```
 require_once 'facebook.php';

    $appid = "*****";
    $app_secret= "*********";


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appid,
    'secret' => $app_secret
    ));

     $facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken); 
     $user_info = $facebook->api("/user"); //returns null
```

Note that the access token is correctly recieved to the server.
So is there a solution to this problem? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In your facebook app settings, do you have your app domain set with "Website with Facebook Login" checked and a site url?

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using the string "/user" in the API call path?

if so, that will not work unless you're trying to access a user whose username is 'user'

`/me` is a shortcut which refers to the current user, use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working for me

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

    $appid = "*****";
    $app_secret= "*********";


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appid,
    'secret' => $app_secret
    ));

     $facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken); 
     $user_info = $facebook->api("/me");
```